# In spacemacs, search occurances of pattern A only in files with name matching pattern B

Tags: spacemacs

In spacemacs, I often search for patterns within my project via `SPC-*` or `SPC-/`. These commands allow me to input a pattern to search for, such as the name of a function I would like to jump to the definition of.

Sometimes, I would like to restrict that search to files of only a certain type, such as searching only `*.elm` files and omitting all others (`*.hs`, `*.sql`, etc.).

**How can I specify filenames for my pattern search?**
I.e., How to search for pattern A only in files with name matching pattern B?

I'm wondering if there is some special key I can type as part of my search query to accomplish this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `ag` as a search backend, you can do `SPC-/ -G<file name regexp> <search pattern>`, see `man ag` for details.

I am not sure if the `grep` backend can do something similar, I think the internal call to `grep` is much more complex and adding flags tends to hang my emacs session. From a shell you can run `grep -n <search pattern> <file pattern>`